# Accessing a server using VPN connection

Tags: dns, vpn

I am trying to connect to a university server using a VPN client. I can connect to the client. Also, if I ping the server by name and by IP address, they both work:

ping servername
ping serveripaddress

However, I cannot access the server from the browser if I type: 
\servername
\serveripaddress

and also I do not see anything in Network apart from my own computer. I changed my Workgroup to the correct Workgroup, and it still doesn't work.
Also, as my DNS suffix I use the domain name as well as the FQDN, but it doesn't work either.

I restarted after each of these changes, but it didn't help.

I read that when I have a VPN connection working and I am also able to ping the server to which I want to connect, it is most probably DNS resolution problem. But I do not know anymore what to do (I checked and tried the correct DNS suffixes).

Do you know what should I do more? I am using Windows 7.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to use [UNC pathing](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/windowsnetworking/g/unc-name.htm). Assuming that you're getting your network settings from DHCP, are you getting a WINS server?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I do not get a WINS server. I mean, the value in properties/advanced/WINS is empty. I am sure also that the problem is with my computer and not the server, because 1.) I cannot connect to other servers either, and 2.) other people can connect to those servers. I get also the error: Error code: 0x80070035 The network path was not found.

Comment: Without a WINS server, your machine would need to be on the same network segment to be able to use a UNC path. I would speak to your network admin for the VPN and ask if there's a WINS server you can add to your computer.